# Disconnect some input-hidden layer connections in MLP neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using Neural Network (NN) wizard in MATLAB for some implementations. Also i can use code-based version of NN in MATLAB which is available after construction NN by wizard (It is clear!).

When we provide our NN with MATLAB, it is a fully connected input-hidden layer. For example, if you have 4 inputs in the input layer and 2 neurons in the hidden layer, we have fully connected relation between 4 inputs and 2 neurons in hidden layer. I am going to manipulate this connections. For example, disconnect 3rd input connection to 1st neuron and 2nd input connection to 2nd neuron in hidden layer. How is it possible by the MATLAB?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read completely documentation of NN in MATLAB. With the following command we can access to each connection and change their weights and bias so that the desired connection gets off duty!

```
For a NN with one hidden layer:

Network.IW{1,1} = The matrix of Input weights to Hidden layer.
Network.LW{2,1} = The matrix of Hidden layer weights to Output layer.
Network.b{1,1} = The matrix of bias between Input to Hidden layer.
Network.b{2,1} = The matrix of bias between Hidden layer to Output.
```

Then, we can set `0` to those connections (both weights and bias) between Input and Hidden layer as our desired. With this type of configuration, we can re-construct the neural network infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomize this switching off and on, of some nodes, you can also use the `dropoutLayer` in Matlab. This works best for deep NNs.

https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.dropoutlayer.html