# How to create a Skip-Layer feedforward neural network in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, feed-forward

I would like to create a neural network with skip layer connections in MATLAB. Is there any way to modify "newff" function to allow for direct connections from input nodes to output layer?

Comment: Have you done any research, or considered other approaches (such as using instead of modifying newff)? This question is currently very broad.

Comment: Well I need to show that a feedforward network can be seen as sum of a linear model + some nonlinear parts. I know that R package for neural network supports skip layer connections but I should find a way to do that in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found a solution for this yet, I had a similar problem. Note that if you have a look at the cell arrays `net.IW` and `net.LW` you can modify the adjacency matrices within these structures and essentially modify the weights of the connections in the neural networks any way you want, including connections from the input layer to any other layer (including the output) for example. You then just need to modify these matrices so that you'll get the skip-layer structure you desire.

For more information check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505884/disconnect-some-input-hidden-layer-connections-in-mlp-neural-network-in-matlab) out, it is similar to what you're asking.